# To-Do List App with Sync, Repeating To-Dos for daily food tracking

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, data-synchronization

I'm on a diet plan and I'm looking for a simple repeating  To-Do checklist application for food tracking with the following features:

- Sync to a cloud or web-based service where changes can be made
- Able to repeat to-dos list
- Notes
- Groups / Filters / Folders for various food groups such as fruits, vegetables,

Can anyone recommend a to-do app with this functionality?

Comment: Is the idea that you'd have a to do item for each item of food you need to make sure and eat that day? That sounds different from the app I use, but you might check out http://loseit.com which gets the syncing and notes.

Answer (score 1):

Check the out "Things". Things is a great to-do app that has cloud sync, repeating to-dos, and notes. For organization, a "to-do item" can be tagged, placed in a project (like a folder), or in an Area Of Responsibility (like a tag). Things is very flexible and would probably work for your diet plan.

You can try the app for free, but the Mac version is $49.99, and iPhone version is $9.99. Unfortunately, there is no web-app.

https://culturedcode.com/things/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at "remember the milk" http://www.rememberthemilk.com